# VueJS: Vuex doesn't update View after modifying State

Tags: view, vue.js, state, vuex

I'm currently working on a web project. I use VueJS 2 and Vuex 2.
The problem is that When I update a subArray of my state, the state is not bind to the view.

my State:

```
export const state = {
 comments: [],
}
```

and mutation:

```
...
export const mutations = {
 ADD_REPLY (state, { id, comment }) {
  let c = state.comments.find((c) => c.id === step);
  if (c.replies === undefined)
   c.replies = [];
  c.replies.push(comment);
 }
}
...
```

In this exemple, when I push a reply (ADD_REPLY), it's not update in the view. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: See https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vues-reactivity-rules

Comment: @Phil I tried to use it like this `Vue.set(c.replies, c.replies.length, comment);` But it's not working

Comment: Maybe try `c.replies = c.replies.concat(comment)`.

Comment: The comment is well has been added, but not bind to the view, still not update

Comment: It seems to be a mutability issue. I feel like you're going to have to do something like `Vue.set(state.comments, indexOfTheComment, commentWithRepliesAdded)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) you only need to worry about reactivity when setting property names. In your case this would be setting `c.replies = [];`. So instead use `Vue.set(c, 'replies', []);`